# Joomla 3 - failed login redirection landing page, two login menus

Tags: redirect, joomla, authentication, failed-installation

In joomla you can set up several menu login pages with different landing pages defined for each of them.

I need different landing pages for failed logins based on which login page the user used (just like with a successful login). As it is now, Joomla sends failed login users always to the same page.

I.e. if you create login menu page *Login* and login menu page *Post article* and you set up the redirection for the successful logins, first to a profile page, and secondly to a post an article page. This works. However, if the users fail on login, they are always redirected to the login menu page *Login* and never to the *Post article* login page.

The failed login redirection is defined by the  code in /components/com_users/controllers/

```
else
{
// Login failed !
$data['remember'] = (int) $options['remember'];
$app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
$app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
}
```

It is possible to change `index.php?option=com_users&view=login` into the address we want as lading for failed login?

Comment: You wouldn't want to modify Joomla's core like that. Doing so means cumbersome maintenance and potential for breakage at update time.

Comment: I'd look to an extension such as this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/6495

Comment: I can't answer the question yet due to the time limit.

I think I found an answer.

It works when I change the 

   `'index.php?option=com_users&view=login'`

into

    `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

the, php remembers the page I came from. I don't know if there are drawbacks to it yet. It does exactly what I want that it would though.

**isherwood:**
I don't want to change this in the core files, I will override this via the template.
I tried the plugin, but it only changes the default failed login redirrect page. It doesn't recognize two different login pages.

Comment: I see it is not possible to overide it through template...

Comment: Right. It's not a template. :-) I'm not familiar with how plugins override core functionality.